# Is it able to fetch transactions from previous snapshot via api?

Tags: iri-legacy-api, snapshot

With current global snapshot feature, transaction data would be wiped out and only addresses with balances would remain. I know we can search these data from some DB archives. But are we able to fetch these transactions **via api** from a full node which chooses to reserve the database? If yes, is there any example?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: No.
The more complex answer: If you download this DB, uses it in your own full-node and get all the milestones after each snapshot, you could implement something like this.

I think you are probably looking for the simple answer :)